# process.env throws Uncaught ReferenceError but process.env.NODE_ENV does not

Tags: javascript, environment-variables

In my client-side javascript file if I run the following I get no error:

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); // outputs development or production
```

But if I run the following then I get an error:

```
console.log(process.env) // Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

Why is this happening? Using Webpack 5 for bundling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're using a bundler that replaces `process.env.NODE_ENV` with another value.
For Webpack, it's [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) doing the dirty work (and setting the Webpack [`--mode`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/) option [automatically adds the plugin](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#specify-the-mode)); for e.g. esbuild [it's `define`](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#define).

Your resulting bundled JavaScript will not have `process.env.NODE_ENV` at all, just a static string `"production"` or `"development`". However, just `process.env` will not be replaced (unless configured so), so you're getting a reference error.

Comment: In my Webpack config I have `new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: 'true',
          __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: 'false'
        }` thats it. Nothing else. So how is process.env.NODE_ENV being processed?

Comment: Just augmented the post with that information.

Comment: Coincidentally I had just dug into the related Webpack code last week, so it was fresh in my mind. Glad I could help!